# Return only object words but not functions defined with colon as the suffix

Tags: rebol, rebol3

When an `object!` is created as below:

```
REBOL []


Room: make object! [
    price: copy ""
    area: copy ""

    total: func [] [
        price * 2
    ]

    set 'total2 func [] [
        price * 3
    ]
]
```

The result of `probe Room` is:

```
make object! [
    price: ""
    area: ""
    total: make function! [[][
        price * 2
    ]]
]
```

The function `total:` is printed, but the function `total2` is not.  I have a script where I saved a `map!` as a series of `repend [hash Room]`. Before I added the function `total`, the `Room` object would return only the words, like

```
make object! [
    price: ""
    area: ""
]
```

After adding the `total` function, it is also returned and it modifies the output which is was I want to avoid.  So, besides changing `total:` to `set 'total` is there a way to return only the prior output?

In the [Rebol/Saphir book](http://learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html), there's a `/display` word or refinement, but it does not seem to work in my system Atronix 3.0.0.4.40:

```
** Script error: cannot access display in path Room/display
```

So what to do? Create a `map!` of `price`, `area` and its values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The function total: is printed, but the function total2 is not.

Binding-wise, your `total2` is bound to the enclosing context...not the object.  So if you were to run that from the console:

```
>> Room: make object! [
    price: copy ""
    area: copy ""

    total: func [] [
        price * 2
    ]

    set 'total2 func [] [
        price * 3
    ]
]

>> probe :total2
make function! [[][price * 3]]
```

It sounds like you were doing it in the first place because you were wanting to "hide" the functions from the object's output, yet still have them be there.  Generally it's probably not the best idea to probe or debug-dump an object as the way of serializing it if you don't want to see the functions.

On a technical point of the way objects work in Rebol: when you put function member values in an object like this, they really are *unique* functions.  So every one of the objects with a function member has a copy of the body, with its words bound specifically to the identity of words of *that object instance*.  While a bit of a performance puzzle, having each object be fully independent lets each one be customized.  But if this is a problem for your purposes, then you would keep your functions outside of the object.

If that's not a problem, you should probably write a serialization function for those cases when having the functions just be *in* the object is bothering you.

Though it's not what you're looking for in this case, I'll mention something kind of cool... PROTECT/HIDE:

```
>> Room: make object! [
    price: $1'000'000.99
    area: 20x40

    total: func [] [
        price * 2
    ]

    sneaky: does [total]
]

>> protect/hide 'room/total

>> room
== make object! [
    price: 1000000.99
    area: 20x40
    sneaky: make function! [[][total]]
]

>> room/total
** Script error: cannot access total in path room/total

>> room/sneaky
== 2000001.98
```

It's a way of removing things from visibility or binding, but any previously existing bindings will still work.  And if you use it as the parent object for a MAKE!, the hidden items will still be there:

```
>> o: make Room [price: $304 area: 10x20]
== make object! [
    price: $304
    area: 10x20
    sneaky: make function! [[][total]]
]

>> o/sneaky
== $608

>> o/total
** Script error: cannot access total in path o/total

>> o/total: does [print "can't overwrite it, either!"]
** Script error: cannot access total in path o/total:
```

Comment: What happens if you o: MAKE room [ ]. Do 'O have total-func or not?